# Is it possible to mix Ruby code and HTML like in PHP?

Tags: php, html, ruby, cgi

I would like to generate a HTML page with Ruby, and I am curious if it is possible to mix somehow the static part HTML and the Ruby statements which generate the dynamic parts. Is there a godd technique for doing this?

Comment: google "ruby erb" for a start :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
change your file name to `file_name.html.erb`

```
<form action="<%= ruby here %>" method="get" >
  <%= rand()  %> <!-- Pure ruby here -->

  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil%> <!-- options in ruby -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an HTML string in pure Ruby code using the [dom](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) gem that I have developed. Using it, you can do things like:

```
require "dom"
["foo".dom(:span, class: "bold"), "bar"].dom(:div).dom(:body).dom(:html)
# => "<html><body><div><span class=\"bold\">foo</span>bar</div></body></html>"
```